# PHP imap - get the maximum capacity of mailbox

Tags: php, imap

In my gmail account, for example, I cannot have more than 15Gb of messages. Is there a way to retrieve this number somehow with php's imap functions?

I know there is imap_mailboxmsginfo(), which will tell me how much of memory I am using right now (350MB, for example), but it doesn't say that 15GB is the maximum, that's the problem..

Comment: gmail supports the QUOTA extensions.  You should be able to use the imap_get_quota, or imap_get_quotaroot function.  The quota root name appears to be just "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you may achieve it with the following code of lines : 
May be it can help to you. Can you please try it once?

```
array imap_get_quota ( resource $imap_stream , string $quota_root );
$mbox = imap_open("{imap.example.org}", "mailadmin", "password", OP_HALFOPEN)
  or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$quota_values = imap_get_quota($mbox, "user.kalowsky");

if (is_array($quota_values)) {
   $storage = $quota_values['STORAGE'];
   echo "STORAGE usage level is: " .  $storage['usage'];
   echo "STORAGE limit level is: " .  $storage['limit'];

   $message = $quota_values['MESSAGE'];
   echo "MESSAGE usage level is: " .  $message['usage'];
   echo "MESSAGE limit is: " .  $message['limit'];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`imap_get_quota()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-get-quota.php) looks like what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `QUOTA` extension is not required to be present. This means that some IMAP servers might implement it, while others won't. If the server doesn't imaplement `QUOTA`, then you're out of luck and cannot really get the data you're looking for.